# NullPointerException when switching between fragments with single Activity android

Tags: android

Good day all. Quick question, For a single activity that holds multiple fragments via a footer, is this a correct way to implement switching between fragments? this code is present for every fragment

private void showMyFragment() {

```
  FragmentTransaction ft = fragmanager.beginTransaction();

  if(fragmanager.findFragmentByTag(MY_FRAG_TAG) != null){ //different Tag for different fragment

     ft.replace(R.id.dashboard_fragment_container_id, myfragment, MY_FRAG_TAG);  //NUllPointerException sometimes here
     ft.commit();
    }

  else {

      myfragment = new MyFragment();

          ft.replace(R.id.dashboard_fragment_container_id, myfragment, MY_FRAG_TAG);                     
      ft.addToBackStack(null);
      ft.commit();
  } 
}
```

the stack trace is:

```
01-23 15:07:20.432: E/AndroidRuntime(30834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 15:07:20.432: E/AndroidRuntime(30834): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 15:07:20.432: E/AndroidRuntime(30834):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(Unknown Source)
01-23 15:07:20.432: E/AndroidRuntime(30834):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(Unknown Source)
01-23 15:07:20.432: E/AndroidRuntime(30834):    at com.company.example.DashBoardActivity.showComparisonDashboard(DashBoardActivity.java:431)
01-23 15:07:20.432: E/AndroidRuntime(30834):    at com.company.example.DashBoardActivity.onClick(DashBoardActivity.java:359)
01-23 15:07:20.432: E/AndroidRuntime(30834):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
```

Assuming this code is present for every method that holds a fragment.. like showMyFragment1() for MyFragment1, showMyFragment2() for MyFragment2 etc.. Also there is a different Tag for different fragments. is this a good way to switch between the fragments in the single Activity footer or is there a cleaner way. i sometimes get a NullPointerException in the line commented above. and am not sure what am doing wrong there when switching. Thank you.

**update** just realized that the trouble occurs after an orientation change. only one of my fragments can change orientation. the others are locked to portrait. so after an orientation change occurs on the priviledge one and then i switch fragments, the problem occurs.

Comment: @njzk2 please find the update question. Also the fragment Tag changes for each fragment. this code was just for one fragment. Thank you

Comment: i'd say `myfragment` looks like a good candidate